# Improving Zhang's prime gap

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I am referring to [Zhang's paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/su3uak2a057yrqv/YitangZhang.pdf).

Since the set $\cal{H}$ is a subset of $[3.5\times 10^6, 7\times 10^7]$, shouldn't the prime gap he obtained be less than
$ 7\times 10^7 - 3.5\times 10^6$ rather than $7\times 10^7$, as stated in his paper? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: In fact, Zhang did not optimize his method. I expect his method to be greatly optimized and get a much smaller gap. But the important part of his result is not the size, but that there is a size at all.

Comment: @mixedmath: Agree, but I am just wondering if what I said is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the gap size can be brought down to below 60 million (in particular, to 59,874,594) by more careful choice of parameters, according to [a short preprint by Timothy Trudgian](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6369).

Edit: [Further work](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132632/tightening-zhangs-bound) has reduced the bound to 13,008,612.

Edit: Following Maynard's work and the subsequent improvements of the Polymath project, the bound has been lowered to 246: [Variants of the Selberg sieve, and bounded intervals containing many primes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4897)

Comment: Where might one obtain Trudgian's preprint?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6369

Comment: You may also want to look at the discussion in the Secret Blogging Seminar, both the post and the comments: http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/i-just-cant-resist-there-are-infinitely-many-pairs-of-primes-at-most-59470640-apart/

Comment: At the link I posted, the gap has been improved, being currently at most 13,008,612.

Comment: Could you provide links for the updated improvements (like the number 246 you just changed) if they are available? Thanks